# Login with php curl with token

Tags: php, parsing

i'm trying to login to https://www.amzreviewtrader.com/ (thanks to https://www.amzreviewtrader.com/account.php page).
I noticed that there is always a token whick will change every refresh. So with first curl i get it.
After, i try to pass token, email and password with post method. but i can't login, i don't know why.

```
function grab_page($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
    }

    function login($url){

    $get_token = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($get_token, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
      $response = curl_exec($get_token);
      $html = str_get_html($response);
      $token = $html->find('div.col-xs-12 form.form-horizontal input')[0]->value;
      echo $token;

        $login = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "account_token=".$token."&email=xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xx&password=xxxxxxx");
        return curl_exec ();
        curl_close ();

        grab_page("https://www.amzreviewtrader.com/product-list.php");
    }
```

Comment: it's probably anti-CSRF token, which WILL change every time you load the url.

Comment: Friend, token is based on phpidsession.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get the token:

```
function getStr($string,$start,$end){
$str = explode($start,$string);
$str = explode($end,$str[1]);
return $str[0];
    }

    $token = getStr($url, 'var token = "','"');
```

Comment: Try encoding the token with: `".rawurlencode($token)."` .

Comment: Nothing my friend. i tried to put an echo after

curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "account_token=".$token."&email=xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xx&password=xxxxxxx");
        return curl_exec ();

but it doesn't print my string!